# manipulate data in datagridview vb net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a table sales(invoice,dateinv,seller,grade)

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Sales"
Dim daHeader As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
Dim dtSales As New DataTable
daHeader.Fill(dtSales)

dgvheader.AutoGenerateColumns = False
dgvHeader.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Date", .DataPropertyName = "dateinv"}) 
dgvHeader.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Seller", .DataPropertyName = "seller"}) 
dgvHeader.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Grade", .DataPropertyName = "grade"}) 
dgvHeader.DataSource = dtSales
```

the value of grade column is between 1-3.
How to display Grade value in Datagridview into :
1 = "Excellent"
2 = "Good"
3 = "Enough"

thanks,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use datagridwiew.cellformatting event

```
Private Sub dgvHeader_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvHeader.CellFormatting

Dim sHeader As String = dgvHeader.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

    If ucase(sHeader) = "GRADE" Then

        If e IsNot Nothing Then
            If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Select Case e.value '-----------> assumed grade as numeric field
                  Case 1 : e.Value = "Excellent"
                  Case 2 : e.Value = "Good"
                  Case 3 : e.Value = "Enough"
                End Select                    
            End If        
        End If
        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lucky : you may vote this as the answer .. it will be fair enough :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can hook the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) Event

**Edit**

Code from @matzone will work if you set the **Name** of the column, but you only set `Headertext` and `DataPropertyName`

So Try this:

```
Private Sub dgvHeader_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvHeader.CellFormatting

Dim sHeader As String = dgvHeader.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText

    If sHeader = "Grade" Then

        If e IsNot Nothing Then
            If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Select Case e.value '-----------> assumed grade as numeric field
                  Case 1 : e.Value = "Excellent"
                  Case 2 : e.Value = "Good"
                  Case 3 : e.Value = "Enough"
                End Select                    
            End If        
        End If
        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I only changed this line:

```
 Dim sHeader As String = dgvHeader.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText
```